# Compare NSString with Chinese letters ios

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

Does anyone know if it works well to compare NSStrings with chinese letters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it works well.

```
NSString *chnString = @"中文, 汉语";
if ([chnString isEqualToString:@"中文, 汉语"]){
    NSLog(@"Equal");}
else
    NSLog(@"NOT Equal");

if ([chnString isEqualToString:@"中文, 汉"])
    NSLog(@"Equal");
else
    NSLog(@"NOT Equal");
```

And results are:

> 2011-09-27 15:08:14.527 iProj-iPad[3716:207] Equal
>   2011-09-27 15:08:14.528 iProj-iPad[3716:207] NOT Equal